# COM interfaces declared in C++

Tags: c++, com, marshalling

Usually to create COM interface one should declare it in IDL file. In the project I work on I have one COM interface declared in *.h file in C++:

```
struct DECLSPEC_UUID("A67177F7-A4DD-4A80-8EE1-25CF12172068") ISomeService : public IUnknown
{
    virtual ~ISomeService() {}

    virtual HRESULT Initialize(const Settings& settings) = 0;

    // ...
};
```

Moreover the method Initialize takes a struct that contains std::string fields as its parameter.
The corresponding COM class is implemented in C++ and it is used from another C++ module.
This works fine until I run the code under AppVerifier. It causes access violation exceptions to occur.

So my questions are

1. Is it right to sometimes declare COM-interface in *.h file?
2. If yes is it right to specify C++ types as parameters for COM interface methods? Or should I always use COM compliant types in such cases (BSTR etc)?

Comment: I have never seen COM interfaces defined only in .h file. Where is the CoClass for this is defined? Anyway, if you are using a custom class, COM should know about this class so that it can marshal this class so that the data is passed properly from the caller to the called method. Please see section 5.5 in this link(http://progtutorials.tripod.com/COM.htm) on how to achieve this.

Comment: @Unni: Why should there *be* a `coclass`?  This is an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sure, you can describe a COM interface without using IDL. But you won't be able to use such IDL features like type library and marshalling code generation. However if you are using the COM component as in-proc server only (DLL), and it's ok with you to distribute the .h file to the clients - then this approach will work fine.
2. Avoid using C++ types in the interface, because it may result in access violations when dealing with memory across DLL boundaries. Better use plain C types, or COM types